# wxCheckListBox Filtering function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, wxwidgets

I'm currently trying to apply a filter to the wxCheckListBox (for a search of specific elements). So far i have no idea how to do it. The Problem with it is, that I don't want to have a copy of the Control and always delete the unnecessary items from the copy, and as soon as the search changes it has to be copied again from the original and delete the items again. I was wondering if there is a way to simply hide some items and not the entire control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the items in a `wxListBox` or `wxCheckListBox`. To have this sort of dynamic control over the items appearing in the control you need to use `wxListCtrl` in virtual mode.

However it's not usually really a problem to delete some items from a `wxListBox` and then insert them back (or, even simpler, store all the items, delete some of them from the control and then, to revert, clear the control and restore all the initially stored items).

Comment: it is indeed true, but i am worried about the performance (the Control will contain about ~7000 items)

Comment: Don't use `wxListBox` for that many items, use `wxListCtrl` in virtual mode or `wxDataViewCtrl` instead which allow you to return only the items really needed (i.e. currently shown on screen) on demand.

Comment: A valid point. Do i assume correctly that even with the two different controls i still have to use the idea of deleting the items that shouldn't be visible? I haven't come across another way after studying the wxwidgets documentation. Is that correct?

Comment: With `wxListCtrl`/`wxListView` with `wxLC_VIRTUAL` style or `wxDataViewCtrl` you don't actually add the items to the control at all but just provide the control with access to them. So you don't actually delete anything, but just stop returning some items (and refresh the control).